# How to check if username already exists with PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know this got posted a ton of times, and I've tried almost every answer on this site, but nothing will work. Whenever I try to run the registration process, the if statement gets skipped even tho the username is already taken.
Here's the part of the code:

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users (username, password) WHERE username = '".$username."'")

if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
{
  echo 'taken';
} 

else
{
...
}
```

I should also note that I saw a thread with someone saying that they had the same issue like this one because they had to use mysqli, but nothing else apart from that. Thanks.

Comment: `mysql_query` is dead, it's been removed from PHP 7. Please, stop using it and at the very least use `mysqli`. PDO is an even better option.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Could I please signup using a username of "**`foo' AND '0'='1`**" ? (I want to signup multiple times using that same username.)

Comment: @b0ss filthy. Have provided you with clear explanation. Have a try and let me know if you face any hindrance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **MYSQL:** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

MYSQLI Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

PDO Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

> Advantages of using PDO:

Most PHP programmers have discovered how to use MySQLi and MySQL extensions. However, PHP Data Objects (PDO) offer ways to work with objects and retrieve prepared statements which make work much easier.

PDO is a database access tool in PHP which enables uniform access across multiple databases. It does not support syntax's specific to databases, but it permits relatively seamless switching between different platforms and databases, which can simply be done by changing the connection string.

Below is a little information about PDO, mainly directed at programmers who are still using MySQL and MySQLi extensions, outlining the superiority of the former. Different aspects will be studied in the next few paragraphs.

- **Database support**

The PDO extension has the capability to access any database which the PDO driver has been written for. There are many PDO drivers available, a few of which include PDO drivers meant to access Free TDS, Sybase, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, Firebird/Interbase 6, Oracle Call Interface and PostgreSQL databases, among many more.

The drivers are not automatically available in every system, so you will have to find your available drivers and add the ones that you need.

- **Database connecting**

There are different syntax's to establish database connections which depend on specific databases. When using PDO, you want to ensure that your operations are wrapped in try/catch blocks and that you utilize the exception technique.

In normal cases, only a single connection need be made, and connections are closed by programming the database handle as a null. You can look up more specific options and syntax's in various resource sites.

- **Error handling**

PDO allows for the use of exceptions for error-handling, which is why you’re advised to wrap PDO in try/catch blocks. This way, PDO can be forced into the relevant error mode attribute in order to produce an exception.

There are three – silent (default), warning and exception – modes. The latter two are more useful in DRY programming. ‘Warning’ error mode is useful for debugging and the ‘exception’ mode allows graceful error handling while hiding data that a person might use to exploit your system.

- **Inserts and Updates**

PDO condenses the common insert and update database operations into a simple two-step process: `Prepare >> [Bind] >> Execute`. With this method, you can take full advantage of PDO’s prepared statements, which offer you protection against malicious attacks through SQL injection.

Prepared statements are pre-complied SQL statements which may be executed several times by sending this data to the servers. They are advantageous in that data used within the placeholders is automatically protected from SQL injection attacks.

> Hence It is better to use PDO and it will avoid the SQL Injections that are prevailing now a days.

**PDO Code to check whether the username and passwords fields exist in the DB:**

```
 <?php
//Connections
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=s','root', '*');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$username = $_POST['username']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];   
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$password1 = $_POST['passwordconf'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


//Verifcation 
if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($password1)){
    $error = "Complete all fields";
}

// Password match
if ($password != $password1){
    $error = "Passwords do not match";
}

// Email validation

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error = "Enter a Valid email";
}

// Password length
if (strlen($password) <= 6){
    $error = "Choose a password longer then 6 character";
}

if(!isset($error)){
//no error
$sthandler = $handler->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :name");
$sthandler->bindParam(':name', $username);
$sthandler->execute();

if($sthandler->rowCount() > 0){
    echo "User Already Exists.";
} else {
    //Securly insert into database
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (name ,username, email, password, ip) VALUES (:name,:username,:email,:password,:ip)';    
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(

    ':name' => $name,
    ':username' => $username,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':password' => $password,
    ':ip' => $ip

    ));
    }
}else{
    echo "error occured: ".$error;
    exit();
}
```

Hope so this reference might be useful for you to develop the codes in the future project by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for this. After reading your post, I am surely switching to PDO as soon as I find a free/cheap host which supports php 7 (currently using 000webhost and it only supports php 5.1).

Comment: I need to know the reason for my down vote to this answer. Please justify

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most elegant solution.  But it will check if a username exists.

```
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE username=?');
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $get_instances = NULL;
    $stmt->bind_result($get_instances);
    $instances = NULL;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $instances = $get_instances;
    }
    $stmt->close();

    if ($instances == 0) {
        //whatever you want to happen        
    }
}
```

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful to put the above code in context:  https://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Comment: This worked with a few minor changes for me, thanks. I'll be using this method till I find better hosting which has servers with newer php versions and probably switch to PDO extensions after that.